# How To select all the targets with touches rect in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

i want to select my targets using touches rect

am creating my unselected dots by coding like these:-

```
    targets1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

         for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                for (int y=0; y<3; y++) {
                    CCTexture2D *texture = 
                    [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"UnselectedDot.png"];
                        block = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture rect:CGRectMake(0,0,82,82)];
                    CGFloat xoffset = ((block.contentSize.width)*10) + (((block.contentSize.height)-175)*y);
                    block.position = ccp( (i*82)+80,xoffset);
                   [bg1 addChild:block];

                    [targets1 addObject:block];
}
}
```

below is my sample output .

- - - 
- - - 
- - - 

now i need to select all the dots by touches method. i written coding like these:-

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {
 //   NSLog(@"%@",targets1);
   for (CCSprite *sprite in targets1) {
       CGRect dotrect = CGRectMake(sprite.position.x, 
                             sprite.position.y-95, 
                             sprite.contentSize.width, 
                             sprite.contentSize.height);
       CGFloat x = location.x;
       CGFloat y = location.y;
       CGFloat width =  (location1.x - location.x);
       CGFloat height = -(location1.y - location.y);
       CGRect touchrect = CGRectMake (x, y, width,height); 
       NSLog(@"dotrect = %f,%f,%f,%f",dotrect.origin.x,dotrect.origin.y,dotrect.size.width,dotrect.size.height );                        
       NSLog(@"touch rect = %f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f",touchrect.origin.x,touchrect.origin.y,touchrect.size.width,touchrect.size.height,location1.x,location1.y);
       if( CGRectContainsRect(dotrect, touchrect))
       {     //collision detection
            NSLog(@"am touched dot ");
       }
     }
}

- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
    location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]]; 
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
    NSLog(@"am touched began");
    return YES;

}

- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    location1 = [touch locationInView:[touch view]]; 
    location1 = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location1];
   location1 = [self convertToNodeSpace:location1]; 
}
```

as per above coding my concept is :- using touches began and touches ended am making rectangle here.. inside these touchrect  my unselected dot rect came means collsison detected.. then i can do my stuffs there. but its not colliding all.

am not getting were am making mistake.

Edit :1

now i got why coillision not working...  actually insidemy touches rect having multiple rect.. so only ... here, am using rectcontainsrect.. tahts the problem.. any other method to rect having several rect for colllsion detection..

Comment: what are the results your getting?  Do the touch began/ended methods get hit when you add a breakpoint?

Comment: @nycynik  actually if i try to drag square format in my iphone screen.. nothing happening ... same if itry the samething in single unselected image its collision detection.. onething i understand dotrect must be varying everytime.. so its not matching with my touches rect...

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
CGRectContainsPoint([dot boundingBox], location);
```

inside the CCTouch.. methods (as you wish depending on what you want to do).